# Selecting first letter of multiple words

Tags: python, python-3.7

I need to display the first letter of multiple words, which have been gathered from multiple items in a list

Tried gathering the list items, seperating them using `word.split(" ")` and using `song[0][0/1]`

```
for word in song:
    songWords = word.split(" ")
    songLetter1 = songWords[0][0]
    songLetter2 = songWords[1][0]
    print("")
    print("The artist is", artist, "and the first letter of the song is", 
           songWord1, songWord2)
```

hoping for "s" and a number, depending on the randomly chosen item

Comment: What is your error/problem?

Comment: Show please, input and desired output

Comment: Can you provide a sample 'song' and what the output 'songWord1' and 'songWord2' should look like?

Comment: @Lafexlos It gives me a list index out of range error

Comment: @RamanKishore Songs are just 'song 1, song 2 etc.' in an external .txt file and my bad songWord should be songLetter, should be the letter I want to output

Comment: @15007LRGS change `songWords[1][0]` to `songWords[0][1]` in your code, it will work

Comment: Which means, _most likely_ you have items in `song` that don't have space in it.

Comment: `songWords` returns n list that have 1 item . You can't use `songWords[1][0]`

Comment: @OmerTekbiyik songWords has 2 items, as there are two words in each song

Comment: Why can't you add text present in `.txt` file and how you are defining `song`?

Answer (score 0):

After you read from text from the .txt file, you can store it in a string. I'm assuming that string looks like songText below.

Try:

```
songText = "song 1, song 2"
songs = songText.split(",")
print(songs)
artist = "artist 1"
for song in songs:
    song = song.strip() # To remove spaces before and after the text.
    songWords = song.split(" ")
    # The below lines will work assuming there are at least two words in the song.
    songLetter1 = songWords[0][0]
    songLetter2 = songWords[1][0]
    print("")
    print("The artist is", artist, "and the first letter of the song is", 
           songLetter1, songLetter2)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @15007LRGS You're welcome. Feel free to accept the answer by clicking on the 'tick mark' symbol for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If input is a list

```
song=["hey","lol"]
for word in song:
    songWords = word.split(" ")
    songWord1 = songWords[0][0]
    print("")
    print("The artist is and the first letter of the song is",songWord1)
```